# Как в JPA Entity ограничить размер id типа String чтобы не выбрасывался SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

Использую spring+jpa.
Есть сущность, у которой `id` или поле `name` является `String`:

```
@Entity
class Customer{

 @id
 String id;

 String name;
...
}
```

Если `id` - поле типа `int` - все ок.

Если `Srting`:

> SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Использую базу MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Column(length = 10)
    private String id;
```

Вопрос решается добавление аннотации @Column из import javax.persistence.Column;

Answer (score 2):

MySql не позволяет хранить использовать первичные ключи больше 1000 байт (1 символ это 1-2 байта в зависимости от кодировки). Судя по всему, твоё исключение падает во время вставки, если у тебя слишком длинный ключ (полу `String id`). Аналогичная ситуация в этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)

Comment: А как, если я создаю таблицу не сам, а средствами jpa(create-drop) ограничить id строкового типа определенной длинной?
Я попробовал @Size(max=20) из javax.validation.constraints.Size, но это не помогло

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov как насчет https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#length(), Не забудь удалить из базы старую таблицу.